# Run single method from commandline using Maven and Jnunit

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I am tryinf a apporach to run a single test method from commandline using maven or either Junit.  My project is build in Junit Framework with Maven.

I have parallel execution in place to run methods in parallel. When I try to run this from commandline, it is still running all testmenthds in parallel.

```
mvn -Dtest=<Classname>#<testmethodname> test
```

Would anyone help, how to acheive to run single testmethod or sepcific test methods from commandline.

Versions:
junit - 4.9
maven-compiler-plugin - 2.5.1
maven-surefire-plugin - 2.8

this is log for refrence

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <ProjectName> 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @  ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @  ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @  ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) @  ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Automation\......\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='methods', perCoreThreadCount=false, threadCount=6, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Destroying 1 processes
Destroying process..
Destroyed 1 processes
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Comment: Which JUnit version do you use?

Comment: <version>4.9</version>

Answer (score 1):

The surefire parameter for excuting a single test is `test` not `Test` so you should invoke the following Maven command:

```
mvn -Dtest=<ClassName>#<TestMethodName> test
```

For example, given ...

- A test `FooTest` with a test method: `foo()`
- A test `BarTest` with a test method: `bar()`

... you could invoke the following:

- Run FooTest.foo()

  ```
  mvn -Dtest=FooTest#foo test
  ```
- Run FooTest.foo() and BarTest.bar()

  ```
  mvn -Dtest=FooTest#foo,FooTest#bar test
  ```

Comment: tried 
mvn test -Dtest=.....Test#policy_getcustomersummary
mvn surefire:test -Dtest=.....Test#policy_getcustomersummary

still its executing all testmethods from the given class

Comment: @luckyvasul Could you update the question to state which version of the maven Surefire plugin you are using. The `-Dtest` parameter is verified with JUnit4 and > 2.12.1 of maven-surefire-plugin. See [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) for more details on version compatability.

Comment: it worked ..after updating to Surefire plugin to 2.19... not I can execute only 1 particular test or set of test methods...Thank You guys.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling mistake spotted buddy, correct one is **-Dtest** and not -DTest

```
mvn -Dtest=<Classname>#<testmethodname> test
```

Additionally, as you are already running multiple tests in parallel, you can also use below mentioned pattern to execute like test methods.

**Example:**

```
mvn -Dtest=Classname#testMethod1+testMethod2+testMethod3 test
```

Enjoy... ;)

Comment: mvn test -Dtest=<classname>#<testmethod> .. still running all test methods

Comment: did u mention test in last?

Comment: tried
`mvn test -Dtest=.....Test#policy_getcustomersummary
mvn surefire:test -Dtest=.....Test#policy_getcustomersummary
mvn -Dtest=.....Test#policy_getcustomersummary test`

tried as such, still all testmethods in the class are executing